# spawnSync input not working as expected (want array of inputs)

Tags: node.js, interpreter, brainfuck

my code:

```
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');
let child
child = spawnSync('brainfuck', ['-e', '>,[>,]<[.<]'], { input: 'hello' })
console.log('stdout ', child.stdout);
console.log('stdin', child.stdin);
console.log('error', child.error);
```

github code: https://github.com/fabianishere/brainfuck
this brainfuck code reverts 'hello' to 'olleh', but code just can catch 1 input each time, i would need an array of strings: 'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o', finishing with ^@ (null). How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

{ input: 'h\ne\nl\nl\no' }

\n acts as 'enter', separating the strings.